# How to create a node package for angular 2?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, node-modules

I am new to angular2.

I have created npm packages with javascript for nodejs.

currently I am interested in writing npm packages for angular 2 but major issue I am having is angular2 uses typescript.

can someone please explain how angular2 packages are built for node?

any inputs?

Answer (score 1):

You can create NPM packages with any Javascript-transpiling language. You can specify the tasks needed for running your app in the package.json file. For example:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc:w\" \"lite-server\"",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
}
```